# When trying to prove some $M$ is an $A$-module, with $A$ being an algebra, how do I deal with the set of generators of $A$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Suppose I want to find out if $M$ is an $A$-module, with $A$ being an algebra with a set of generators $S$ and $R$ a set of equations satisfied by the generators of $A$.

For the sake of simplicity, suppose there are only two elements in the generating set $S$, say $x, y$, and assume further that $R=\{x^2=y\}$. I am now interested in showing that $M$ is an $A$-module.

I have defined multiplication only between the generators $x, y$ of $A$ and the elements $m$ of $M$. Our teacher said this does not suffice to give $M$ an $A$-module structure. He said that we need to also make sure that $x^2*m=y*m$ for all $m\in M$, after defining the multiplication. Why is this required?

Comment: An algebra over which ring/field?

Comment: @Bernard: Over $\mathbb{C}$. Sorry for failing to mention this. I thought it was pointless to say which.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that an abelian group $M$ is a left $R$-module if the scalar product
$$ R \times M \to M, (r,m) \mapsto rm $$
satisfies the usual axioms.

We need this scalar product to be well-defined!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can I please ask you something I'm not understanding still: how/why is not checking if $x^2*m = y*m$ holds true an obstacle to the well-definedness of multiplication map?

Comment: It's the natural extension to scalar products of the usual statement that a map $f: X \to Y$ is well-defined if $f(x) = f(y)$ whenever $x = y$.

Comment: Well, for a map, $f$, to be well defined, $a=b$ must imply $f(a)=f(b)$

Comment: @Nawaj, bounceback. Well, I do know what it means for a map to be well-defined. I was asking about how you would *use* the relation when checking that the map is well-defined (or where the relation is supposed to be used)?

Comment: Sorry to answer a question with another, but how have you defined your multiplication? That should give a good idea

Answer (score 1):

By defining what the generators do to elements of $M$, you are giving a putative action of $A$ on $M$. What remains to check is that the relations act like zero.

So in your example, if $M = \mathbb{Z}^2$ and $x$ acts by flip-flopping the factors and $y$ acts as the identity, you're all set. But if $x$ acts by multiplication by $0$ and $y$ acts by multiplication by $-1$, you haven't defined the structure of an $A$-module on $M$.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Can you please explain just a little what you mean by "relations act like zero"?

Comment: @Mark sure. In $A$, the element $x^2 - y$ is equal to $0$. So if $m \in M$ it had better be the case that $(x^2 - y)m = 0$ for this to give a well-defined action of $A$ on $M$.